# Zend - Get everything after base Url (Controller, Action, and any params)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to create a login system with Zend that when a user tries to access a restricted page they will be taken to a login page if they aren't signed in.  The issue I'm having is getting the URL they were trying to access before hand.  Is there a Zend Function that will return everything after the base Url?  For example, I need "moduleName/controllerName/ActionName/param1/value1/param2/value2" etc etc.  to be sent as a querystring param to the login page (ex: login/?redirect=controllerName/actionName/param1/value1/param2/value)

I can get the controller and action name, and I get get the params, but it already includes the module, controller, and action as well.  I'd like to just get what I need.  I worked out the long way of doing it like this:

```
$controllerName = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
$paramArray = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
$params = '';

foreach($paramArray as $key => $value)
    $params .= $key . "/" . $value;

$this->_redirect('/admin/login/?redirect=' . $controllerName . "/" . $actionName . "/" . $params);
```

but even then I end up with params like module/admin/controller/index/ etc which I don't want.  So, how can I just get everything as a string like it is in the URL or at least just the params in a string without the controller and action as param values?

**EDIT:  Here is my current solution, but there has got to be a more elegant way of doing this **

```
            $moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
            $controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
            $actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
            $paramArray = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $params = '';

            foreach($paramArray as $key => $value)
                if($key <> "module" && $key <> "controller" && $key <> "action")
                    $params .= $key . "/" . $value . "/";

            $this->_redirect('/admin/login/?redirect=' . $moduleName . "/" . $controllerName . "/" . $actionName . "/" . $params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can pass along the last request URI like this:

```
$this->_redirect('/admin/login/?redirect='.urlencode($this->getRequest()->REQUEST_URI));
```

Comment: This seems like a good candidate but it also returns the baseUrl.  Is there any way to just get everything starting with /moduleName/controllerName/actionName/param1/value1/param2/value2 ??

Comment: To get everything after the baseUrl, I don't have a solution on hand.  In my situation, after logging in, I just take the full URI and redirect to it as follows:
`$this->_redirect($full_url, array('prependBase'=>false));`

Does that help?

Comment: Hey Derek, I wasn't aware that _redirect took that array of options with the prependBase option.  That's good to know, thanks.  For now I have everything setup as mentioned in my edit above, but may switch to this at some point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i know its an old question but for future references:

```
$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

that should get you what you want..

Answer (score 2):

No idea why Zend doesn't have this feature, but this is how I have accomplished it.  My use case was that i wanted to redirect old URLs that went directly to controllers using the default routing, to a new API url structure that used routes.

```
$filtered_params = array_diff_key(
  $this->_request->getParams(), 
  array_fill_keys( array('controller', 'module', 'action' ), 1) 
);

$this->_redirect('/api/1.0/?' . http_build_query($filtered_params));
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but heres a solution thats worked for me. From here you may want to url encode it etc

```
$currentRoute = substr($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(),strlen($this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` to encode/decode the individual param strings.  An example would be:

```
// outputs %2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.php
$path = '/path/to/file.php';
echo urlencode($path);
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution using the Zend Framework.  I don't have the path, and I'd like to get all parameters that are included in the original request